# RPI 3B+, Wifi super slow (10x slower than onboard) when using USB Wifi despite huge antenna

Tags: wifi, usb, raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+

TL;DR, usb-wifi works, but it's extremely (!) slow compared to onboard wifi, even though the dongle has a big antenna and a a better signal quality. I looked far and wide and did all I could find, but to no avail. Seems like this must be a settings issue...

---

PI 3B+ 
I'm running
`cat /etc/debian_version
9.9`

- I have tested the bandwidth with iperf3 on local network and with speedtest-cli and the same results came in.
- The power management is OFF
- sudo apt-get dist-upgrade has been done
- firmware-realtek package is installed and up to date
- The chipset is RTL8188CUS, which is supposedly supported by the firmware-realtek package

---

SPEED DATA:

The onboard wifi has speeds around

`pi@octopi:~ $ speedtest-cli
Download: 29.29 Mbit/s
Upload: 24.50 Mbit/s`

with Link Quality

`Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm`

While the usb wifi has link quality

`Link Quality=99/100  Signal level=67/100  Noise level=0/100`

but speeds only

`Download: 0.34 Mbit/s
Upload: 2.46 Mbit/s`

What is happening here?!

Any ideas warmply appreciated!

Comment: Are both connected to the same router? What is the timing if you ping the local router?

Comment: A small help : check the `dbm TX power` (use `sudo ifconfig wlan1`), check the MCS index (you must be connected to the AP) and the current bitrate of your connected device  and his protocol  used (802.11 ?) and the current Bandwidth (use `sudo iw wlan1 info`)... 802.11n allow 54Mb/s maximum , but he can allow most important bitrate depending of your device capabilities and conf. etc... Provide `sudo iw wlan1 info` (you must be connected to the AP) and `sudo iw phy phy1 info` outputs for more help (adjust the commands with your device name). Also , check `sudo dmesg` when device hot-plug.